# Is async/await useless in MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net

In MVVM where the ViewModels update the Views via INotifyPropertyChanged events, there doesn't seem to be much room for the cool feature of async/await; executing the continuation on the captured synchronization context of the invoker.

So, if this is the case, then who will actually use the features of async/await in a modern UI based app? In this context, "who" can also mean what pattern, e.g. MVC-variation.

I can think of the following as a good way of using TAP

```
ViewModel.Age
{
  set {
    await Model.SetAge(value);
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
  }
}
```

however, having this run on the captured syncContext, does not really help out much.
Actually, we could put all this in the model instead.

```
Model.Age
{
  set {
    await SetAge(value);
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
  }
}
```

and now, we would really like the syncContext NOT to be the captured one.

Comment: Task-based Asynchronous Pattern, but really I just mean the async/await functionality in C#5.

Comment: Why would it be useless? You can await all sorts of different things. Updating UI, fetching data, listening for messages...

Comment: It would be useless because the whole feature of executing the callback on the calling context is not needed in MVVM since the updating is done via events.

Comment: What about commands that need to perform a lot of work and then update a property?

Comment: Where does the alleged lack of room come from? Instead of doing something that takes a while while holding up the UI thread you release the UI thread and do the work somewhere else. It's not different from using the worker pool, but much easier to write and you get to say where your continuation has to execute. And you're already using events to notify the UI.

Comment: @strmstn I am not questioning the need for asynchrony, just the special way that a/a handles the callback when called from the UI thread, i.e. executing NotifyPropertyChanged event on the UI thread, which is useless.

Comment: Yes. I agree. The syntax is much easier. However, as I wrote to @strmstn, the default synchronization context that the continuation gets executed within, is the UI thread when the call is made from the UI thread. This is pointless in MVVM, but it makes alot of sense if the UI is _not_ updated through INotifyPropertyChanged, but directly from the VM. This would be the case in passive view (MVP), but afaik, MVVM is considered much more compatible with WPF.

Comment: If you already have value then why await?

Comment: You can opt out from the default context http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually, having `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` raised in the UI synchronization context is *required* for data binding.

`async` / `await` do force you to make a distinction between *properties* (which represent the current state and are always synchronous) and *commands* (which represent actions and may be synchronous or asynchronous). Property getters and setters *cannot* be `async`, so your example code with an "async set" is not a possible approach.

`async` enables asynchronous commands. You can use command binding to asynchronously handle routed commands, or pass an `async` delegate to a `DelegateCommand`, or use your own `ICommand` implementation. Whichever way you'll do it, you end up with an `async void` command event handler.

A realistic example is to have the VM properties set the M properties in-memory, and have a `SaveCommand` with an `async` handler. It's common to have `async` handlers interact with an additional VM property (`SaveInProgress` or maybe a common `Busy` shared with other `async` handlers) so that the UI can respond appropriately when the command is in progress (usually at least causing `CanExecute` to return `false`).

So your `async` handler ends up looking something like:

```
private async void SaveCommandExecute()
{
  try
  {
    // Set VM property; updates View appropriately.
    Busy = true;

    // Do the actual saving asynchronously.
    await Model.SaveAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Update the VM with error information.
    Error = ex.Message;
  }
  finally
  {
    // Let the VM know we're done.
    Busy = false;
  }
}

private void SaveCommandCanExecute()
{
  return !Busy;
}
```

Note that the VM properties (`Error` and `Busy`) are updated in the captured UI synchronization context.

---

This illustrates the central concept of `async` MVVM: commands may be `async`, but the properties (such as `Busy`) always represent the current state.

If you're adding `async` to an existing MVVM app, you'll find yourself with several additional properties indicating business and possibly also progress updates (e.g., percent complete). Depending on your application, you may permit multiple asynchronous operations at the same time. You'll need to think of good ways to add this information to your Views; I find this to be the most challenging part of `async` MVVM apps.

Comment: I was under the impression that INPC was an event such that it pushed a message on the UI thread which caused the UI thread to pull the value of the property in question from the VM.

Comment: INPC is just a regular event. It won't jump threads unless you specifically implement it that way (which I don't recommend, but some people do choose to do that).

Comment: Great answer. Helped cement some of the overall concept of async operations in C#.

Comment: _"It won't jump threads unless you specifically implement it that way"_ -- sort of true. Yes, in the broader sense, there's nothing special about the INPC interface that would handle cross-thread issues. But WPF's _use_ of the interface does. If `PropertyChanged` is raised in the wrong thread, a WPF binding will automatically dispatch to the UI thread for the purpose of handling that event. I.e. the WPF event handler itself does the cross-thread dispatch. IMHO this is an important point to get right in the above answer.