# How to call a function after the viewModel is downloaded?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, binding, async-await

I start a search and after it finishes and I finish the viewModel I want to show a message if I didn't find anything.

I have 3 approaches so far:

1.) Convert the `App.ViewModel.LoadData()` to an async-await-method and start my function afterwards.

2.) Do something similar to this, but with a function:

```
void NewSearch_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding("IsLoadingJobs") { Source = DataContext };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(
        prog, ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminateProperty, binding);
}
```

3.) hacking.

The 1. approach didn't work that fine because I never used async-await before and it didn't seem easy.
The 2. approach sounds easier but I couldn't find any "binding" to start a function.
The hacking approach would worka nd is easy but not nice: In the viewModel I'd see that I get an empty array, could fill in 1 special triggerword or something and then on the view-side ask for this word with an if. Would work but I don't like it that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Embrace `async/await`. If you have difficulties, ask it as a separate and more specific question. There's already a lot of great answers on this subject, e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13310521/1768303).

Comment: Okay, I'll go through this. My problem is/was that I don't know what to search for. When I found a method it doesn't automatically mean this is THE method to do it. That's why I was asking for the best/a good way ;)
async/await then. thx :)

Comment: A good decision. The `async/wait` wiki has some great resources to begin with: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info

Answer (score 0):

First, a warning: don't write `async void LoadDataAsync`, write `async Task LoadDataAsync` instead. Also don't forget to add `Async` to the end of your functions.

Now, you should have properties that indicate if the search/load is in progress and if it is done. Those are generally used to toggle visibility of certain UI elements like progress bar or a message "nothing is loaded".

That is a clean, MVVM based pattern to show operation in progress indicator as well as to show that the operation is done. And that there are no results.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto what @Toni has mentioned

To give a simple example your view model would look something like this after the above changes

```
public class ViewModel
{
   /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the search resulted in data
    /// </summary>
    public bool? HasResult
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hasResult;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hasResult = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("HasResult");
        }
    }

   /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating a search result message
    /// </summary>
    public bool? SearchResultMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.searchResultMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hasResult = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SearchResultMessage");
        }
    }

  //Your command or action that searches for results
  public void Search()
  {
    //Does what it used to do

    //Check if there is result
    if(results.Count == 0)
    {
       this.HasResult = false;
       this.SearchResultMessage = "Nothing is loaded";
    }
  }
}
```

Bind HasResult to the view (this includes the elements whose visibility would be affected by the state of this property) using a [boolean to visibility converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
somthing like this

```
<TextBlock Visibility = "{Binding HasResult, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConv}}" Text="{Binding SearchResultMessage}" ></TextBlock>
```

You can always have varitions of this approach based on how you want your view to behave for e.g. indicate progress as well, but the gist of it is follow the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)