# WPF context menu with custom item template freezes on running long time commands

Tags: wpf

I try to dynamically generate context menu with custom item template. But when user run some long time command, context menu freezes on screen. How to avoid context menu freezing?

Here a sample:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MenuHangUpTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="525" Height="350">
    <Grid Width="500" Height="300">
        <TextBlock Text="Test test">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextCommands}">
                    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Caption}" />
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MenuHangUpTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TestCommandItem> ContextCommands
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCommandItem();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestCommandItem
    {
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return new TestCommand();
            }
        }

        public string Caption
        {
            get
            {
                return "Test";
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestCommand : ICommand
    {
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            // context menu freezes on screen during running this command
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should move your long running processing off of the UI thread, if you want to keep the UI responsive

Comment: this should be useful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304270/is-async-await-useless-in-mvvm) HTH.

Comment: and this is really easy according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx) :-)